# Asp.net iframe page payment gateway integration

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

I am implementing ebook website, where we allow other partners' website to add our book advertisement widget.

When people click on the book adv, redirect back to our website and continue the checkout process with PayPal.

One of our partner does not want to checkout from our website. He want the checkout flow inside his website itself.

I provide the iFrame page to embed in. However, PayPal checkout is not displaying inside his website. It show as full page and after successfully payment it redirect back to our website download page.

Is there any way or other payment gateway which i can use in iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your client an option, to change the redirect page to his site including your page in iframe, or what ever you design,

Then add this return page to the parametre you send on PayPal the **"return"** with this parameter. Also the cancel parameter must be similar, the **"cancel_return"** parameter

The same way I believe that you can design a page on your site that looks like your client, setup by your client, and do the job, entering and exit to your client site.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will go for the first way "_redirect page to his site including your page in iframe_" as they don't want to see our webpage url.